# jQuery doesn't like .on and .append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a weird problem.
I'm currently working on loading posts using PHP, AJAX and MySQL. The code structure itself looks like this:

## **My code structure**

--- **main.js** ---

```
$(window).load(function(){
     initAjax();
});
```

--- **ajax.js** ---

```
function initAjax(){

//   Toggles a navigation

     $(document).on('click', '.btn.open', function(){
         ... toggles a window ...
     });

//   Add new posts

     $(document).on('click', '.btn.refresh', function(){
         $.ajax({
              ... ajax stuff ...,
              success: function(html){
                   // Show new posts
                   $('.post_container').prepend(html);
              }
         });
     });
}
```

## **So what is the problem?**

When I append new posts they'll show up, but I am not able to click .btn.open anymore - Shouldn't 'on()' fix this? When I go to the Google Chrome console.

**Does somebody know a potential way to solve the problem?**

### **Edit:**

1. The appended posts are the same as the default loaded posts!
2. '.btn.open' exists (div with class="btn open")
3. I am using jQuery v2.0.3 (*so .on should work!*, **.live and .delegate were replaced by .on!**)
4. Removed an error message that was created by a corrupted Chrome extention = No change.
5. Created a .gif showing the problem in action: http://d.pr/i/cJB3
6. **FIXED!** @[cmorrissey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602732/cmorrissey) found a small solution by replacing $(document) with $('body')

   ## **BUT**
7. This fix doesn't seem to be a perfect solution since $(document) normally has to work! Since I want *clean* code, I am totally going to try out @[Potherca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153049/potherca)'s [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) method and probably I'll find the solution this way. **Thanks**

Comment: The .btn.open that you can't click - Is that loaded with the ajax?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @Krishna jQuery v2.0.3

Comment: @EsbenBoye-Jacobsen As you can see, everything is loaded through AJAX

Comment: I assume `$.function(){}` is a typo and it's really `$(function(){})`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Indeed. Fixed it.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DaAKL/

Comment: @aduck - Can you post your mark up as well? Check if `.btn.open` really exists? Also put an alert inside the event & check if it fires>

Comment: in fact jquery hates those jerks!

Comment: try to use `.live` instead of `.on`. `.live` should survive a page change

Comment: @SparK .live was replaced by .on when jQuery v1.7 came out.

Comment: Have you tried this with that iMacros plugin disabled? Does the result change?

Comment: @SparK: When the page changes *ALL* JavaScript is un-loaded.  Plus `.live()` has been removed from jQuery.

Comment: If you have `e.stopPropagation()` or `return false;` on some handler between the element and the `document`, your `.on` handler won't fire.

Comment: @Rooster: What are you talking about?

Comment: @Potherca Thanks for fixing the error in the console -> This does not affect the not working .on :/

Comment: Use `'body'` instead of `document`

Comment: @cmorrissey This fixes it! But maybe there is a "cleaner" way to solve the problem itself. But thanks anyways!

Comment: @RocketHazmat jquery doesn't like .on and .append because those guys are jerks

Comment: @Rooster I think `.on` and `.append` still owe jQuery money or something...

Comment: @aduck That `.gif` is awesome by the way. How the hell did you make that?

Comment: @Potherca LICEcap (http://www.cockos.com/licecap/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `'body'` or `document.body` instead of `document`.

```
    $('body').on('click', '.btn.refresh', function(){
         $.ajax({
              ... ajax stuff ...,
              success: function(html){
                   // Show new posts
                   $('.post_container').prepend(html);
              }
         });
     });
```

Reason: The addition of content to the body doesn't bubble up to the document level (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11621), it looks like you can also use `window`

Comment: Could you explain, why?